# B-spline for non-polynomial splines in r

Tags: r, regression, interpolation, splines

I intended to fit a 2D co-ordinate cloud, which resembles an incomplete ellipse. When I tried using **bs()** function from "splines" package in R to get the fitting curve (which is used to generate the B-spline basis matrix for a polynomial spline), it looked like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/428Ko.png).

But what I intended was something like [**this**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKDL1.png).

To feed the parameters to bs() and plot it, I just followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15839076/4588604)

```
mod <- lm(y ~ bs(x, knots = seq(0.1, 0.9, by = 0.1)))
pdat <- data.frame(x = seq(min(x), max(x), length = 100))

## predict for new `x`
pdat <- transform(pdat, yhat = predict(mod, newdata = pdat))

# plotting
plot(y ~ x)
lines(yhat ~ x, data = pdat, lwd = 2, col = "red")
```

Is there any way to achieve what I intended?

Thanks!

Comment: looks to me as if you want x and y exchanged

Comment: sure for this case I would get solution if I just interchange x and y. But if the data cloud resembled full ellipse or circle, then there would be problem.

Comment: This is a really interesting question, do you have some data to play with? I think you could start from a parametrization of an ellipse and use `nls` to fit the parameters.

Comment: Ya, I actually started with ellipse fitting from [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/fitting-an-ellipse-to-point-data/), but want to generalize the process for all kind of data (like if data resembled 'alpha' shape). [Here](http://i.cs.hku.hk/~wenping/SDM/TOG_SDM.pdf) the author discuss the implementation issues (on page 13), where control points as input is intended from the user.